# Aggregating Dapper Multi Mapping Results To Object with List Within a List

Tags: c#, .net-core, dapper

I'm relatively new to dapper and trying to aggregate the data it returns. I'm trying to figure out how to map results to an object with a list property that also has a list property.

My objects:

```
public class Employee()
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public List<Employement> Employments { get; set; }
}

public class Employment()
{
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    public List<JobInfo> JobInfo { get; set; }
}

public class JobInfo()
{
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string Salary { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

My method:

```
var historyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Employee>();

var results = await connection.QueryAsync<Employee, Employment, JobInfo, Employee>(
    sqlQuery,
    (e, em, ji) => {
        Employee emp;
        if (!lookup.TryGetValue(e.Id, out emp))
                historyDictionary .Add(e.Id, emp = e);

        if (emp.Employments == null)
                emp.Employments = new List<Employment> { em };
        else if (!emp.Employments.Exists(ec => ec.CompanyId == em.CompanyId))
                emp.Employments.Add(em);

        //map JobInfo

        return emp;          
    }, SplitOn: "Id"
);
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around mapping the JobInfo. I know I can't just do the same thing I'm doing when mapping Employment since it's a list under Employee and doing Employee.Employments doesn't give me direct access to JobInfo object, so I would assume I would need to use linq

This is what I'm trying to get

```
Id,
Name,
new List<Employment> {
    new Employment1 {
        CompanyId,
        CompanyName,
        HireDate,
        new List<JobInfo> {
            new JobInfo {
                JobTitle1,
                Salary,
                StartDate,
                EndDate
            },
            new JobInfo {
                JobTitle2,
                Salary,
                StartDate,
                EndDate
            }
        }
    }
    new Employment2 {
        CompanyId,
        CompanyName,
        HireDate,
        new List<JobInfo> {
            new JobInfo {
                JobTitle1,
                Salary,
                StartDate,
                EndDate
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And would like to make sure the right jobinfo gets mapped to the right employment

Also, I would like to fully understand dapper mapping, is it mapping sql data per row of data?

Sample sql data

```
Id      Name        CompanyId   Company     HireDate    JobTitle    Salary      StartDate       EndDate
001     employee1   123         company1    01-01-2010  job1        12345       01-01-2010      01-01-2012
001     employee1   123         company1    01-01-2010  job2        23456       01-01-2012      02-02-2015      
001     employee1   456         company2    01-01-2016  job3        34567       03-03-2016      null
002     employee2   123         company1    02-02-2015  job4        23789       02-02-2015      null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly, your Dapper query is not quite right:** when using multi-mapping, the objects are split vertically in the resultset (some columns for the parent object, some for the child), and you need to provide the *split* points i.e. the starting columns for each object.

**Then you map each object into its nested location, depending on whether it exists or not.** For another level of nesting, you simply take the previous level and lookup again.

```cs
var historyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Employee>();

var results = await connection.QueryAsync<Employee, Employment, JobInfo, Employee>(
    sqlQuery,
    (e, em, ji) => {
        if (!lookup.TryGetValue(e.Id, out var emp))
            historyDictionary.Add(e.Id, emp = e);

        if (emp.Employments == null)
            emp.Employments = new List<Employment> { em };
        else
        {
            em2 = emp.Employments.Find(ec => ec.CompanyId == em.CompanyId);
            if(em2 == null)
                emp.Employments.Add(em);
            else
                em = em2;
        }

        em.JobInfo = em.JobInfo ?? new List<JobInfo>();
        em.JobInfo.Add(ji);

        return emp;          
    }, SplitOn: nameof(Employment.CompanyId) + "," + nameof(JobInfo.JobTitle)
);
```

You can simplify the logic a bit by assigning default `List` objects in the constructors. Normally I would use `Dictionary` instead of `List`, and that is also simpler for doing lookups:

```cs
var historyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Employee>();

var results = await connection.QueryAsync<Employee, Employment, JobInfo, Employee>(
    sqlQuery,
    (e, em, ji) => {
        if (!lookup.TryGetValue(e.Id, out var em2))
            historyDictionary.Add(e.Id, em2 = e);

        if (!emp.Employments.TryGetValue(em.CompanyId, out var em2))
            emp.Employments.Add(em.CompanyId, em2 = em);

        em2.JobInfo.Add(ji);

        return emp;          
    }, SplitOn: nameof(Employment.CompanyId) + "," + nameof(JobInfo.JobTitle)
);
```

You should also look into `QueryMultiple`, where you have multiple `SELECT` queries, and you map them in yourself. This prevents a lot of duplicate rows in some circumstances.

Comment: Could you elaborate more when you say the objects are split vertically? 
Do you mean it process each data per column instead of per row? I posted a sample sql data on my original post.

Comment: It splits the parent and child by columns: some columns for the parent object, some for the child

Comment: Is this part a typo? if(em2 != null) { emp.Employments.Add(em); } cause if em2 is not null doesn't that mean that em already exists in the list and we don't need to add it again?

Comment: Yeah sorry fixed